# Why my Adobe Reader renders the PDF like this?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

What's the matter with my Adobe Reader?

I am using Windows 8 with Adobe Reader X1 11.0.3

[image]

Comment: Has anti-aliased rendering been turned off or is was that pdf converted from a postscript file with type3 bitmap fonts?

Comment: How to check if anti-aliased rendering has been turned off or not? This file can be viewed very well on other machines.

Comment: See Edit>Preferences>Page Display>Rendering>Smooth Text